# Is it true that $\preceq$ is well order on $P(x)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ be a finite set and $P(x)$ the power of $X$. Consider the relation $A\preceq B$ if there exists $f: A \to B$ injective. Is it true that $\preceq$ is well order on $P(x)$?

There is a problem that a tried to solve but a can not be able to do it and a really need some help. If someone can give me a hand I'd really thank you.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: It's not even a partial order.

Comment: Try an example - say, work out the case $X=\{1,2\}$.